# What is the optimal way to freeze bananas?

Tags: freezing, bananas

This is something i've always had difficulty finding a foolproof method for. Some swear by keeping it unpeeled, but I find that it's harder to unpeel. If cut up, it looks like you need multiple ziploc bags to ensure that it doesn't turn colors, and that a freezer bags aren't 100% effective.

Is there a tried and true foolproof way to freeze bananas?

Comment: what do you plan on using them for once frozen? the answer may depend on the intended usage.

Comment: Top reason is that they become ripe before I am ready to use/consume. Main planned uses once frozen is usually to make smoothies or banana bread, which the latter I acknowledge requires the banana to be very ripe and mashed.

Answer (score 8):

The best way to freeze bananas so that they don't turn brown and are easy to use, is to peel, slice and flash freeze before you put them in a freezer bag.
Simply peel and slice your bananas. Lay them flat on a piece of parchment paper on a cookie sheet and put in the freezer for 2 hours until they are solid. Transfer them to a freezer bag and remove as much air as possible.
You can freeze these for up to 3 months and they will not turn brown.

Answer (score 3):

#### Note: this is solely for cases where mushed bananas are acceptable/desired

I often make bananas into banana bread, and what I usually do is peel them into a gallon ziploc bag. Next, I mush them inside the bag, then evacuate all the air and squeeze the mash towards the bottom of the bag (and I like to roll it up to help it stay nice an sealed). You can do this one at a time as you collect overripe bananas, or in a group.

This lets you have relatively little browning and also have pre-mashed bananas on-demand.

Additionally, as you add bananas to the bag, use a Sharpie to tally how many you've put in the bag. Then, for banana bread (for example) once you have however many are in a single/double batch you can set the bag aside and start on a new one. You then have a pre-measured quantity of bananas ready to go, and you can even cut a corner off of the ziploc to make it function like a piping bag for mushed bananas.

This works great if you want mushed bananas to bake with, not so well in any other use-case.